# What's the easiest way to change an iPhone app into an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone app that I want to change into an iPad app. I do ***not*** want to make it universal. The result should be an iPad only app. The main problem I see is converting all of my .xib files. I realize that I will have to change some things around manually, but I would like as much as possible (including all of the painstakingly made connections in IB) to carry over. Also, if there are unlikely places where I need to change settings, please give me a hint to that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode has a convert option. It gives you the choice between a new app or a universal one.

This will convert all your NIBs, but quite how useful that is will depend on how thorough you've been with the sizing options in Interface Builder. For me is mostly worked. A couple of minor tweaks for a couple of views and a complete rewrite for some others.

Of course you'll also have to work with view controllers that "manually" build the view.

The gotchas I found were around orientations (iPad apps should work in all four orientations) and with the screen size. There are also some oddities with the keyboard and modal views if you have any of those (there are a few kinds of modal view, and the keyboard does not always dismiss). As ever when you're making automated changes, testing is key.

The full process took me a lot longer than I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Few thoughts for changing iPhone app to iPad app.

1. Xcode has the provision to change the current iPhone app to iPad app by using "Upgrade current target for iPad" menu command.

http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/ready_for_ipad

1. resize all current view to the ipad size 768*1024(portrait) and then resize all the subviews respectively. the connections doesn't get lost by doing this.